# can KSQLDB UDTF achieve ROW_NUM order by function?

Tags: apache-kafka, user-defined-functions, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I am trying to understand before I implement UDTF ROW_NUM, I am wondering whether can UTDF doing sorting among all the row while computing to return as Struct type ?

https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/0.7.1-ksqldb/concepts/functions/